# Replace character in a string conditional on appearance of another character in the string Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string in my code (which consists entirely of lower-case alphabets). I need to replace a character conditional on the appearance of another character after the character I intend to replace in the same string. For example if the character to be replaced is "e" and the conditional character is "t", then we will replace "e" in "forest" but not in "jungle"
Is there is way to do this in a simple manner in Python? Thanks for taking out time for this problem.

P.S Please note that there is no repetition of alphabets in the characters I am working with.

Comment: There is no "i" in "forest", nor in "jungle".

Comment: Thanks Sven for pointing out! Edited!

Comment: What should happen for "greet"?  Should both e's be replaced?

Comment: good point, though it won't impact my code either way since I am only looking for unique characters in a word

Comment: You should give some clarifying examples. What if the word is `feeoeresterette` what output are you looking for?

Comment: @Akavall in this case it would be fttotrtsttrtte since all but the last "e" have t after them, but frankly speaking I am looking only at words why each character appears only once. I think i should edit the question to reflect this important point. Thanks all for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with?

```
if st.find("e") < st.find("t"): 
    st.replace("e","i",1)
```

and its readable

If the occurrence is not unique you can also do

```
>>> pos_t=st.find("t")
>>> "".join(e if (e != 'e' or i > pos_t) else 'i' for i,e in enumerate(st))
```

Comment: @F.J That can be fixed using ``rfind()`` - this only works for the first instance though.

Comment: @FJ: OP is only looking for words with a single occurrence of 'e'

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace all occurrences of `e` that have a `t` after them, you can use the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'e(?=.*t)', 'i', 'forest')
'forist'
>>> re.sub(r'e(?=.*t)', 'i', 'jungle')
'jungle'
>>> re.sub(r'e(?=.*t)', 'i', 'greet')
'griit'
```

This uses a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which is a zero-width assertion that checks to see if `t` is anywhere later in the string without consuming any characters.  This allows the regex to find each `e` that fits this condition instead of just the first one.

Comment: +1 I was just posting this, but messed up. You have it correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'e(.*t)', r'i\1', "forest")
'forist'
>>> re.sub(r'e(.*t)', r'i\1', "jungle")
'jungle'
```

Comment: ``re.sub(r'e(.*t)', r'i\1', "eett")`` will give ``'iett'``.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all 'e's with 'i's if the part that comes before the last t:

```
def sub(x):   
    return x[:x.rfind('t')].replace('e','t') + x[x.rfind('t'):]
```

Result:

```
>>> sub('feeoeresterette')
'fttotrtsttrttte'
>>> sub('forest')
'fortst'
>>> sub('greet')
'grttt'
>>> sub('theater')
'thtater''
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a function that should do what you want:

```
>>> def replace(source, replacee, replacement, conditional):
...     if source.find(replacee) < source.rfind(conditional):
...         return source.replace(replacee, replacement)
...     else:
...         return source
```

Or, if you want it less verbose:

```
>>> def replace(source, replacee, replacement, conditional):
...     return source.find(replacee) < source.rfind(conditional) and source.replace(replacee, replacement) or source
```

Both yield should yield the same results, here are some examples:

```
>>> replace('forest', 'e', 'i', 't')
'forist'
>>> replace('jungle', 'e', 'i', 't')
'jungle'
>>> replace('tales', 'e', 'i', 't')
'tales'
```